# Cannot install tensorflow ver 2.3.0 (distribution not found)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am working on a Deep Learning class, the tensorflow over there is 2.3.0

This is the error when i try `pip install tensorflow==2.3.0`

"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.3.0 (from versions: 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0rc0, 2.14.0rc1, 2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.15.0rc0, 2.15.0rc1, 2.15.0, 2.15.1, 2.16.0rc0, 2.16.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.3.0"

I have two questions:

1. Why the distribution of 2.3.0 no longer available?
2. In this case, how do we install 2.3.0?

Thank you

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: There are also some related questions and issues at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643322/10530728 and at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/60512#issuecomment-1538782491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow 2.3.0 is still available, but TF 2.3.0 was released for Python 3.5-3.8. From the versions displayed to you, it seems that you are using Python 3.9. So, to install this specific version you need to downgrade the Python version. Another option is to use a newer version of TF that supports your current Python version.

The information about the build configurations for Tensorflow can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations) and you can also check the wheels for the version 2.3.0 at [this link](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.3.0/#files) which will indicate Python 3.5-3.8.